# jQuery make this code shorter with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anybody help me modify this jQuery code shorter?

HTML code:

```
 <div id="blinker1"><img src="aaa.png" /></div>
 <div id="blinker2"><img src="bbb.png" /></div>
 <div id="blinker3"><img src="ccc.png" /></div>
 <div id="blinker4"><img src="ddd.png" /></div>
 <div id="blinker5"><img src="eee.png" /></div>
```

jQuery code:

```
function smBlink(){
    //blink 3times
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        $("#blinker1, #blinker2, #blinker3, #blinker4, #blinker5").fadeTo('normal', 0.3).fadeTo('normal', 1.0);
    }
};
```

These taget IDs have same prefix(#blinker) and followed by sequential numbers.
I think array function would help...but I dont know how.
These divs would be increased or decreased in future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use an ["attribute starts-with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("div[id^='blinker']").fadeTo('normal', 0.3).fadeTo('normal', 1.0);
```

This will allow you to add/remove elements with matching IDs as necessary.

If you are able to modify your markup, it would be more efficient to replace the `id` attributes with a shared class name. You can then use a normal class selector:

```
$(".blinker").fadeTo('normal', 0.3).fadeTo('normal', 1.0);
```

This approach would mean the selector engine can take advantage of the speed of the native `getElementsByClassName` function where available.

Comment: Wow! This was so quick and smart. I could not recall this method. Thaaaax!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution:

```
$("div[id^='blinker']").fadeTo("normal", 0.3).fadeTo("normal", 1.0);
```

Here is another, more precise, solution:

```
$("div").filter(function() {
    return /^blinker\d+$/.test(this.id);
}).fadeTo("normal", 0.3).fadeTo("normal", 1.0);
```

Comment: Thanx. Easy and smart solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would add some class common to all divs.

```
 <div class="blinker" id="blinker1"><img src="aaa.png" /></div>
 <div class="blinker" id="blinker2"><img src="bbb.png" /></div>
 <div class="blinker" id="blinker3"><img src="ccc.png" /></div>
 <div class="blinker" id="blinker4"><img src="ddd.png" /></div>
 <div class="blinker" id="blinker5"><img src="eee.png" /></div>
```

And than:

```
function smBlink(){
    //blink 3times
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        $(".blinker").fadeTo('normal', 0.3).fadeTo('normal', 1.0);
    }
};
```

That is as an alternative to "attribute starts-with".

Answer (score 0):

```
function smBlink(){
    //blink 3times
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        $('[id^="blinker"]').fadeTo('normal', 0.3).fadeTo('normal', 1.0);
    }
};
```

You could use this. id^= means any ID starting with "". This way you can be sure the code works without having to modify it every time you modify your HTML.

Another good thing you could do do would be to declare a class for them, and use it instead of IDs.